# How to create an animation for "v-for" element with "v-if" statement in Vue?

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js

I tried to make an animation, but this not working. Also I tried `transition-group`. How can I improve this code to do it workable?
It shows two diffetent lists based on category of data from my `data.json.js` file.

Also with `transition-group` tag it has error:
`<transition-group> children must be keyed: <li>`

template

```
<button @click="switcher = !switcher">SWITCH</button>

<transition name="fade">
    <li v-for="elements in myData" v-if="elements.key == getKey()">
        <span>{{elements.title}}</span>
    </li>
</transition>
```

script

```
data() {
    return {
        switcher: true,
    }

getKey(){
    if (this.switcher) {
        return 'KEY'
    } else {
        return 'ANOTHER KEY'
    }
```

style

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> children must be keyed: `<li>`

You can bind `:key="index"` in `<li>` element. Try this:

```
<transition name="fade">
    <li v-for="(elements, index) in myData" :key="index" v-if="elements.key = getKey()">
        <span>{{elements.title}}</span>
    </li>
</transition>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the anser above won't work as you have to use an transition group for multiple list-elements. You then also need a key in the loop but binding the index won't give you the desired effect - always the last element in the list will be animated.

Better use :key="elements.id"